# Sub-select in a where-in clause

Tags: mysql

Attempting to delete a list of id's generated by a sub-select in a single statement. Is this possible? I've been trying the following:

[edit] corrected query

```
DELETE from store 
WHERE  id in ( SELECT store.id 
               FROM   storeInfo 
               JOIN   store ON storeInfo.store_id = store.id
               WHERE  storeInfo.type = 17 )
```

But this is incorrect syntax ... not sure how to build this properly.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `JOIN` against `storeInfo`? You are not using it in the subquery's `SELECT` or `WHERE`.  Is it possible that `store.type` is supposed to be `storeInfo.type`?

Comment: Why dont you just have "DELETE from store 
WHERE  store.type = 17", since you are anyways not using storeInfo table

Comment: sorry, made a mistake typing here. `type` is in the info  table

Comment: Do you want to delete from _both_ tables `store, storeInfo`, or only `store`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE store
FROM store
JOIN storeInfo 
    ON storeInfo.store_id = store.id
WHERE storeInfo.type = 17
```

Answer (score 2):

After the typo update to the question - you don't need a `JOIN` in the subquery. You can just return `storeInfo.store_id` from the `IN()` subquery.

```
DELETE FROM `store` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `store_id` FROM `storeInfo` WHERE `type` = 17)
```

MySQL would not permit you to use the table `store` in the subquery and then delete rows from it. However, you can use `storeInfo` since it joins directly with `store_id`.

If you need to delete from *both* of these tables (such as if the rows in `storeInfo` become orphaned when their parents are deleted from `store`), use the `JOIN` syntax instead:

```
DELETE
  /* Syntax to delete rows from both tables */
  store, storeInfo
FROM 
  store JOIN storeInfo ON store.id = storeInfo.store_id
WHERE storeInfo.type = 17
```

Review the [MySQL `DELETE` syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) for full details.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson Use it carefully!  I don't think I have ever actually used it in practice. (Just verified in my test database that it doesn't go totally awry)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the join directly into the `delete`

```
delete store from store 
  JOIN storeInfo ON storeInfo.store_id = store.id 
  WHERE  store.type = 17;
```